# How to run a PDF file with wine app (Foxit PDF Editor Pro)?

Tags: linux, wine, winetricks

I want to create a Python function to open a PDF file with the Foxit PDF Editor Pro Application (wine app), my function is as follows:

```py
def open_with_foxit(output_path):
     command = ["wine",
                "/home/lediem/Wine/FoxitPDFEditor/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Foxit Software/Foxit PDF Editor/FoxitPDFEditor.exe",
                output_path]
     subprocess.Popen(command)
```

After running:

`open_with_foxit('/home/lediem/Dropbox/LATEX ALL/FILE HS ONLINE/tài liệu.pdf')`

I get the error message:

```
wine: Read access denied for device L"\??\Z:\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\??\Z:\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\??\Z:\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\??\Z:\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
0180:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
```

even though my links are correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is to set `Z` drive in `winecfg` to `/home` and then replace the corresponding path to `z:/lediem/Dropbox/LATEX ALL/FILE HS ONLINE/documents.pdf`.

Then the PDF file opens normally.